# Adding Variables to Powershell Get-Acl output

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to add the output of a variable to a Powershell cmdlet output

I have the code

`Get-ChildItem D:\Powershell* -Recurse | Get-Acl`

which returns three properties:

```
Path                                Owner                          Access                                                                       
----                                -----                          ------
MyFile.ps1                          MyDomain\MyUser                MyDomain\AnotherUser Allow  Modify, Synchronize...
```

I only want to see Path and Access and I want to add the output `$env:ComputerName` to each result:

```
ComputerName      Path                                Access                                                                       
----              ----                                -----                          
MyServerName      MyFile.ps1                          MyDomain\AnotherUser Allow  Modify, Synchronize...
```

I have tried

`Get-ChildItem D:\Powershell* -Recurse | Get-Acl | Select-Object @{name="Computername"; expression={$env:Computername}}, Path, Access`

Which is close, but I am only see the type of the Access Object:

```
Computername   Path                                                                    Access                           
------------   ----                                                                    ------                           
MyServerName   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\Powershell Scripts\MyFile.ps1  {System.Security.AccessControl...
```

I note the path is fully qualified also but that isn't a particular problem

How do I output the access infomation rather than just the object type?

Comment: How are you planning to display the `Access` property when merged with the other properties? Note that this property contain an array of objects in itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616167/adding-variables-to-powershell-get-acl-output#comment126573805_71616167) commented, the `.Access` property is an array of objects, so to get workable output you can for instance save as CSV, you need to loop over these properties.

Perhaps something like this:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Powershell*' -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.Name  # or $_.FullName if you rather have that
    $comp = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    foreach ($access in (Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Access) {
        # output the combined object
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            File         = $file
            ComputerName = $comp
            User         = $access.IdentityReference
            Permissions  = $access.FileSystemRights
            Type         = $access.AccessControlType
            Inherited    = $access.IsInherited
        }
    }
}

$result
```

Comment: This is probably the only output that would make sense from a data analysis standpoint. Could be worth adding the Owner of the ACL